# Incompatible types Guava Immutable Map to Java util map

Tags: java, unit-testing, guava, lombok

How do I convert a nested Immutable Map to Map.

I have a function definition:

```
double total(Map<String, Map<String, Double>>);
```

Now for my test cases, I am writing in the following format:

```
val input = ImmutableMap.of(key1, ImmutableMap.of(key2, value2));
```

However I get an error Incompatible types: Immutable Map cannot be converted to

```
java.util.Map
```

However if it wasn't a nested Map I am able to do it.

Comment: Using Lombok library

Comment: It's inferring the wrong type. Do it normally: `Map<String, Map<String, Double>> input = ImmutableMap.of(key1, ImmutableMap.of(key2, value2));`

Comment: @shmosel Hmm Interesting yes it worked now. How  come Lombok val didn't detect it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lombok is detecting `ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableMap<String, Double>>` as the type, which isn't compatible with `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`, as explained at length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1553851). To fix, just declare the type explicitly:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> input = ImmutableMap.of(key1, ImmutableMap.of(key2, value2));
```

Alternatively, since your map is evidently read-only, you can also pass it with an [upper-bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html), like this:

```
double total(Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Double>> m);
```

This will allow it to accept any subtype of `Map` as the value type.